# Print matrix on one line

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 A
B C D E F
0 1 2 3 4
```

And I want it printed in one line as following:

```
1 6 2 B 7 3 0 C 8 4 1 D 9 5 2 E A 3 F 4.
```

How is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: How are you storing it? What does your code look like? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: How is your matrix represented? Please provide some code.

Comment: `print mat[0][0]; print mat[1][0]; print mat[0][1]; print mat[2][0]; ... print mat[3][4];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a nested loop.
outer loop is over the distance from (0,0)

inner loop over all valid combinations of i and j that sum up to the distance.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char m[4][5] = { { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' },
             { '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A' },
             { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' },
             { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4' } };

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
            std::cout << m[i - j][j] << " ";
        }
    }

    for (int i = 4; i <= 7; ++i) {
        for (int j = i - 3; j <= 4; ++j) {
            std::cout << m[i - j][j] << " ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix store in array like this :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
  char matrix[4][5] = {{'1','2','3','4','5'},
                       {'6','7','8','9','A'},
                       {'B','C','D','E','F'},
                       {'0','1','2','3','4'}};
  int cols = 5;
  int rows = 4;
  int i = 0;
  for( i = 0; i < cols + rows -2 ; i++){
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= i){
        int k = i-j;
        if(k < rows && j < cols){
            printf("%c ",matrix[k][j]);
        }
        j++;
    }
  }
}
```

I just go through from 0 to total of indexes of row and columns ( in this case from 0 to 7)
for each value of total index, print value with  sum of column and row equal to current total index, if index is avaiable ( lesser than index of column and row), print it, else escape.
For example:

```
0 - 00
1 - 10 01
2 - 20 11 02
```

Btw, it seems like need more loops than others

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `vector<vector<char> >` representation for the matrix(if I assume that you store chars in each cell). An important observation is that for each diagonal you have the sum of the i and j indices a constant and this sum increases by one for the diagonals.

Having noticed this you make an outer cycle over the sum and inner cycle over the x coordinate. Beware not to fall out of the matrix!
Now the easiest c++ way to print the matrix would be:

```
vector<vector<char> > a;
for(unsigned sum = 0;  sum < a.size() + a[0].size(); ++sum) {
  for (unsigned j = 0; j <= sum && j < a[0].size(); ++j) {
    unsigned i = sum - j;
    if (i >= a.size()) {
      continue;
    }
    cout << a[i][j] << " ";
  }
}
```

One can optimize the cycle over j by changing the start value(so that the continue condition is never true) but the code would have been harder to understand. Another nit I did not fix on purpose is that an blank is printed even after the last element. This is yeat another check that needs to be added.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
for( int i = 0; i < matrix.cx; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < matrix.cy; j++ ) {
        std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    // comment following line to make matrix printed in one line
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @qdot: it's not actually a funny way, it's a common zigzag scan pattern.

Comment: @qdot: Common where? I guess DCT transforms are the only place where this is used in practice.. the whole question sounds very much like it's missing a [homework] tag.

Comment: @qdot: the homework tag is deprecated. Next to that, yes it's most often used with DCT's, but DCT's and similar conversions are very common in signal processing/multimedia.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering thou.. zigzagging on asymmetric matrices? this has almost no mathematical sense in the DCT world.